# Where Should I Place my Javascript File in a Flex 3 project?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex

I've got a javascript file that I need to load into my Flex 3 project. I access it in the HTML wrapper like so:

```
<script src="myJSFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I use Google Code's library to access JQuery.

Is it okay to put the javascript file in the html-template folder? The idea being that it would be included in the release build. Any reason not to do so? Will this cause an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason not to do so; and this will not cause an error.  It is not uncommon to change the html-template files.

I'm unclear if extraneous files from the html-template folder, such as the myJSFile.js will be copied into your bin folder during compilating, though.  You'd have to test it out.

The one thing to remember is that changing the SDK on the project will re-create the html-template directory, rewriting all your custom changes.

Comment: Hi www.Flextras, Thank you for the advice. And especially the warning regarding changing the SDK. I'm planning to upgrade mine. So, your poinr it pertinent.